# Define lists based on presence of a factor in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have timestamped data from a manufacturing facility with multiple production lines working simultaneously. What I want to do is classify all production orders for each day based on what was produced on one specific line using `dplyr`. It's not perfect but the `storms` dataset will work as an example:

```
library(dplyr)
storms %>%
  group_by(name)%>%
  mutate(Max_strength =
           case_when(
             status== "hurricane" & category == "1" ~ 1,
             status== "hurricane" & category == "2" ~ 2,
             status== "hurricane" & category == "3" ~ 3,
             status== "hurricane" & category == "4" ~ 4,
             status== "hurricane" & category == "5" ~ 5,
           ))
```

What I want is for every row to have an entry in the column `Max_strength` corresponding to the maximum strength that every hurricane reached. Obviously the attempt I've made here doesn't work but I can't figure out how to get this new factor applied to every entry for the groups defined by `group_by()`.

Comment: Do you mean: `storms %>%
  group_by(name) %>% 
  summarise(Max_strength = max(category, na.rm = T))` If so: replace `summarise`  with `mutate`

Comment: Sorry @Roman, that works in this specific case but is not what I'm after. I don't actually want to summarise the storms data, rather add a factor to every row in the dataset based on the contents of a column for each storm. So if the max strength of a particular storm is 3 then I want a 3 in a new column called Max_strength next to every row for that storm.

Comment: Did you read my complete answer? Particularly the replace part?

Comment: @Roman I misread it as "replace mutate with summarise." When I use that with my actual data it works, so thank you!